# Send email with attachemtns using Microsoft Graph Client API

Tags: c#, .net, microsoft-graph-api

I am trying to send an email with an attachment using Microsoft Graph Client API. I am getting the below exception:

```
{"error":{"code":"RequestBodyRead","message":"Cannot read the value '0' as a quoted JSON string value."}}
```

My code:

```
public bool SendWithAttachment(string emailSubject, string emailBody, string toEmail, string toName)
        {
            var token = AcquireToken(AppConstants.TenantId, AppConstants.EmailClientId, AppConstants.EmailClientSecret, AppConstants.UserId, AppConstants.Password);
            try
            {
                byte[] contentBytes = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(@"C:\Users\user\Downloads\test\test.png");
                string contentType = "image/png";
                MessageAttachmentsCollectionPage attachments = new MessageAttachmentsCollectionPage();
                attachments.Add(new FileAttachment
                {
                    ODataType = "#microsoft.graph.fileAttachment",
                    ContentBytes = contentBytes,
                    ContentType = contentType,
                    ContentId = "testing",
                    Name = "testing.png"
                });

                var recipient = new Recipient
                {
                    EmailAddress = new EmailAddress
                    {
                        Address = toEmail,
                        Name = toName
                    },
                };

                var message = new Message
                {
                    Subject = emailSubject,
                    Body = new ItemBody
                    {
                        ContentType = BodyType.Text,
                        Content = emailBody
                    },
                    Attachments = attachments,
                    ToRecipients = new List<Recipient>() { recipient },
                    BccRecipients= new List<Recipient>()
                };


                var body = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new { message = message });
                var client = new RestClient();
                var request = new RestRequest($"https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/{AppConstants.UserId}/sendMail", Method.Post);
                request.AddHeader("Content-Type", $"application/json");
                request.AddHeader("Authorization", $"Bearer {token}");
                request.AddHeader("Cache-Control", $"no-cache");
                request.AddParameter("application/json", body, ParameterType.RequestBody);

                var restResponse = client.Execute(request);
                return restResponse.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.Accepted;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
```

The exception seems very irrelevant to me. I think it's pointing to email body content type. Any suggestion would be very helpful.

Comment: Why do you use RestClient if you are using Graph API C# SDK?

Comment: Actually this code is from the previous developer. I am just following his method. Email is being sent without attachment but if I add any attachment, then it throws the excption. @user2250152

Comment: Could you try comment `ContentId = "testing",`? I think it should be set only if `IsInline` is `true`

Comment: I'm guessing something has gone wrong with the message content you are serializing. I would also recommend trying the Graph SDK approach - it may help you narrow down the issue with the data

Comment: Error message indicated a JSON string read error, so it may happen at the `SerializeObject`, and use `Graph SDK` should be a good idea. I test in my side with the Access token to [init the auth provider](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/sdks/choose-authentication-providers?tabs=CS#on-behalf-of-provider) then we can use the [graph client for send mail](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-sendmail?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=csharp#request-1). By the way, does your app an asp.net core app?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't have a chance to try your solution yet, loaded with other tasks. Once I get the chance, will let you know. @TinyWang

Answer (score 0):

Using graph SDK may help narrow down the issue like Eric said, since you already had the Bearer token, I think you can try my code below, I can use it to query user information, that why I set a `User.ReadWrite` permission for access token, but you already had the access token, so just using your token into the code:

```
var accessToken = await _tokenAcquisition.GetAccessTokenForUserAsync(new string[] { "User.ReadWrite.All" });
var authProvider = new DelegateAuthenticationProvider(async (request) => {
                request.Headers.Authorization =
                    new System.Net.Http.Headers.AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", accessToken);
            });
var graphClient = new GraphServiceClient(authProvider);
var user = await graphClient.Me.Request().GetAsync();

//use this line to send email
await graphClient.Me.SendMail(message, null).Request().PostAsync();
```

[image]

By the way, I used this code to send email without the attachment before, not sure if it could help you...

```
var jsonStr = JsonSerializer.Serialize(temp);
string token = "your_token";
var httpClient = new HttpClient();
httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", token);
HttpResponseMessage response = await httpClient.PostAsync("https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/sendMail", new StringContent(jsonStr, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json"));
```